# How to implement automatic differentiation in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, automatic-differentiation

So I have a Dual number class:

```
data Dual a = !a :+ !a
instance [safe] Eq a => Eq (Dual a)
instance [safe] RealFloat a => Floating (Dual a)
instance [safe] RealFloat a => Fractional (Dual a)
instance [safe] RealFloat a => Num (Dual a)
instance [safe] Read a => Read (Dual a)
instance [safe] Show a => Show (Dual a)
```

Now I want to write a function that takes in a numeric function and gives its derivative as a numeric function. (Using automatic differentiation).

Here is what I have come up with:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
autoDiff :: Floating a => (Dual a -> Dual a) -> a -> a
autoDiff f = dualPart . f . (flip (:+) 1)
```

Now take for example `sin`, here is what I get:

```
*AutoDiff> :t sin
sin :: Floating a => a -> a

*AutoDiff> :t autoDiff sin
autoDiff sin :: RealFloat a => a -> a

*AutoDiff> :t autoDiff (autoDiff sin)
autoDiff (autoDiff sin) :: (RealFloat (Dual a), RealFloat a) => a -> a

*AutoDiff> sin 1
0.8414709848078965

*AutoDiff> (autoDiff sin) 1
0.5403023058681398

*AutoDiff> (autoDiff (autoDiff sin)) 1

<interactive>:109:1: error:
    • No instance for (RealFloat (Dual a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I have no idea what the error message is telling me. I have tried playing around with `forall` but I can't take a generic function, stick duals through it and return a generic function.

So how can I iterate `autoDiff` to get higher derivatives and is it even possible in Haskell's type system?

Comment: Well you did not implement the `RealFloat` for `Dual`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can't because that would make me eventually implement `Ord` for `Dual` which it really can't do.

Comment: What is the definition of `dualPart`? Why does `autoDiff` have a `Floating` constraint?

Comment: Btw, take note that that `Dual` conflicts with `Dual` in `Data.Monoid`, and that `:+` conflicts with `:+` in `Data.Complex`.

Comment: @DannyuNDos I am not using either of those.

Comment: @DanielWagner just like in `Data.Complex` we have `dualPart :: Dual a -> a`

Comment: @AliCaglayan And the other question? Why does `autoDiff` have a `Floating` constraint? Nothing in `autoDiff` appears to need it, if the `dualPart` type signature you gave is accurate, and removing it should remove the need for a `RealFloat` instance on the wrapped type.

Comment: @DanielWagner The floating constraint is so that I can do floating calculations on dual using their parts. For example sin of a dual requires sin of its parts.

Comment: @AliCaglayan `autoDiff` does not call `sin` anywhere. Only `Num` is needed (for the `1` literal).

Comment: @DanielWagner Yes that has fixed it. It seems so easy now.

Answer (score 0):

You try:

```
autoDiff (autoDiff sin)
```

And Haskell says that:

```
No instance for (RealFloat (Dual a0)) arising from a use of ‘it’
```

Now we could ask where this comes from but let’s write down the types we have and see if we can work out the error without even looking at what it says:

```
autoDiff :: Num a => (Dual a -> Dual a) -> a -> a
sin :: Floating a => a -> a
```

When you work out `autoDiff sin`, you must make `sin` unify with `Dual a -> Dual a` so this requires `Floating a`:

```
autoDiff sin :: (Floating (Dual a), Num a) => a -> a
```

Now you want to take `autoDiff` of this and the same happens:

```
autoDiff (autoDiff sin) :: (Floating (Dual (Dual a)), Num a) => a -> a
```

Now when you type `autoDiff (autoDiff sin) 1`, Haskell determines that this has type `(Floating (Dual (Dual a)), Num a) => a` but it needs to pick some `a` to use to print the result. It will try `Integer` first and then `Double` and then it will fail.

Haskell is looking to satisfy the constraint `Floating (Dual (Dual a))` so it looks for all the ways it can derive an instance for `Dual x` and it turns out it needs `RealFloat x` to do that. So now it has reduced the constraint from `Floating (Dual (Dual a))` to `RealFloat (Dual a)` and it turns out that there is no way for it to derive an instance of `RealFloat (Dual a)` so it fails to compile.